# gcc (6.1.0) using 'wrong' instructions in SSE intrinsics

Tags: c, gcc, sse, intrinsics

**Background**: I develop a computationally intensive tool, written in C/C++, that has to be able to be run on a variety of different x86_64 processors. To speed the calculations which are both float and integer, the code contains rather a lot of SSE* intrinsics with different paths tailored to different CPU SSE capabilities. (As the CPU flags are detected at the start of the program and used to set Booleans, I've assumed that the branch prediction for the tailored blocks of code will work very effectively).

For simplicity I've assumed only SSE2 through to SSE4.2 need to be considered.

In order to access SSE4.2 intrinsics fpr the 4.2 paths, I need to use gcc's -msse4.2 option.

**The problem**
The issue I'm having is that, at least with 6.1.0, gcc goes and implements the *sse2* intrinsic, mm_cvtsi32_si128, with the *sse4.2* instruction, pinsrd.

If I limit the compilation by using -msse2, it will use the sse2 instruction, movd, ie. the one that the intel "intrinsics guide" says it's supposed to use.

This is annoying on two counts.

1) The critical problem is that the program now crashes with an illegal instruction when it gets run on a pre4.2 CPU.   I don't have control over what HW is used so the executable needs to be compatible with older machines, yet needs to take advantage of features on newer HW where available.

2) According to the Intel intrinsics guide, the pinsrd instruction is quite a lot slower than the mov it replaces. (pinsrd is more general but this is not needed).

Does anyone know how to make gcc *just* use the instructions that the intrinsics guide says should be used yet still allow access to all SSE2 through SSE4* in the same compilation unit?

Update: I should also note the same code is compiled under Linux, Windows and OSX using a variety of different compilers so would rather like to avoid or at least have the fewest compiler-specific extensions if possible.

Update2: (Thanks to @PeterCordes)  Seems that if optimisation is enabled,  gcc will revert back to using movd from pinsrd where appropriate.

Comment: Try looking at clang's code generation some time - it will totally re-write certain sequences of SIMD intrinsics with what it considers to be (and often is) a "better" instruction sequence.

Comment: Can you show the code where gcc chooses PINSRD?  Are you sure it's not using it to optimize away a following `_mm_unpacklo_epi32` or something?  (PINSRD decodes to uops for the same ports as MOVD + PUNPCKLDQ, but takes fewer code bytes, so it's a good choice when you've told the compiler it's allowed to use SSE4.2 instructions).

Comment: Anyway, the usual way to handle this is to put your SSE4 functions in a separate translation unit from your baseline x86-64 functions.  Link-time-optimization might be able to help if any of them call small functions from other translation units.

Comment: With `-O0`, gcc amusingly implements `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` by storing the value to the stack, followed by three 32-bit zeros.  Then it uses a gather-style strategy for loading that those four 32-bit elements into a single vector, using two movd/pinsrd pairs and shuffling them together with punpcklqdq.  I think that is the optimal strategy if you have four separate integer values in four separate integer regs, it's just that `-O0` makes it do that with three zeros, so gcc never *just* uses PINSRD for no reason.  ICC and clang both just use `movd xmm0, edi` plus a bunch of store/reloads `-O0`.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback. And yes: we wouldnt have this discussion if the majority vote on the triage queue is correct. But unfortunately, many people have a wrong understanding of the EDIT choice there. The rule of thumb is: when you think " **I** could edit this question and fix it to be good enough to be answered, but I dont have the time right now" ...then you vote EDIT. Otherwise skip, or look out for valid close reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you give the `-msse4.2` flag to gcc's command line during a compilation step, it will assume that it is free to use up to the SSE 4.2 instruction set for the entire translation unit. This can lead to the behavior that you described. If you need code that **only** uses SSE2 and below code, then using `-msse2` (or no flag at all if you're building for x86_64) is required.

Some options that I can think of are:

- If you can easily break down your code at the function level, then gcc's [multiversioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Multiversioning.html) feature can help. It requires a relatively recent version of the compiler, but it allows you to do things like this (taken from the link above):

  ```
   __attribute__ ((target ("default")))
   int foo ()
   {
     // The default version of foo.
     return 0;
   }

   __attribute__ ((target ("sse4.2")))
   int foo ()
   {
     // foo version for SSE4.2
     return 1;
   }

   __attribute__ ((target ("arch=atom")))
   int foo ()
   {
     // foo version for the Intel ATOM processor
     return 2;
   }

   __attribute__ ((target ("arch=amdfam10")))
   int foo ()
   {
     // foo version for the AMD Family 0x10 processors.
     return 3;
   }

   int main ()
   {
     int (*p)() = &foo;
     assert ((*p) () == foo ());
     return 0;
   }
  ```

  In this example, gcc will automatically compile the different versions of `foo()` and dispatch to the appropriate one at runtime based on the CPU's capabilities.
- You can break the different implementations (SSE2, SSE4.2, etc.) into different translation units, then dispatch appropriately to the right implementation at runtime.
- You can put all of the SIMD code into a shared library and build the shared library multiple times with different compiler flags. Then at runtime, you can detect the CPU's capabilities and load the appropriate version of the shared library. This is the approach taken by libraries like [Intel's Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl).

Comment: Thanks, but none are particularly appealing. :-(    The same code has to also be compiled under windows with MSVC and on Macs so the the fewer compiler-specific options in the code the better.

I do find it odd that the compiler has opted to use a slower instruction (twice the latency and 1/3rd the throughput) to do the job though.

Comment: @SimonF It could be a bug in gcc, but you never know; there also might be a good reason why they are using it. Optimizing x86 assembly, especially SIMD code, is so complex that there are often very subtle factors at play for why one instruction might be preferred over another in a particular case. I don't know specifically about this one.

Comment: @SimonF: If you're comparing `PINSRD xmm, r32, i` vs. `MOVD xmm, r32`, you have it backwards.  It's a factor of 3 latency, and a factor of 2 throughput.  And an extra shuffle-port uop.  And a false dependency on the old value of the vector register, since it merges instead of zeroing the rest of the reg.  It's extremely unlikely that gcc used it "by accident" when a MOVD would be equivalent.  That would be a serious compiler bug.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's possible I might be reading the wrong documentation for my CPU or am being incredibly naive but, FWIW, I hacked together a function in asm with a loop doing 100k iterations of 28 pinsrds (in turn being called by another loop of 40k its)  and then another version with the pinsrd replaced by movd.  The former took ~48secs while the latter was about 2.5x faster at 19s.     As for bugs, I wouldn't call it serious,  unlike a previous gcc I used (4.5.2) which certainly had a catastrophic bug in its SSE3 intrinsic support.

Comment: @SimonF: If you used the same XMM register every time, you tested PINSRD latency against MOVD throughput.  Remember, PINSRD merges into the destination register, but MOVD's destination register is write-only.  So a factor of three is about right for Intel SnB-family, where MOVD is 1c latency, one per 1c throughput (with an integer-register source) (http://agner.org/optimize/).  Anyway, yes PINSRD is slower, and no sane compiler would use it if they didn't want the merging behaviour.

Comment: (I rotated using XMM0 through XMM4 on each instruction as dests and EAX through EDX as sources) So, just to check, basically we're in agreement that for implementing  _mm_cvtsi32_si128, gcc should stick with using movd (as it does for the -msse2 option) and not swap to the more general, but slower, pinsrd  which it now uses for -msse4?

Comment: @SimonF: Agreed, but you have still provided zero evidence that gcc is getting no benefit from PINSRD, like optimizing away a later shuffle.  In fact, gcc6.1 -O3 does *not* use PINSRD for `__m128i tovec(int a) { return _mm_cvtsi32_si128(a); }` (https://godbolt.org/g/AS9EUN), but it does use a braindead store/reload sequence without `-march=nehalem`, with or without `-msse4`.  (Agner Fog's microarch guide says he wasn't able to experimentally see a benefit to int-store/movd-reload over `movd xmm,r32` on AMD CPUs, despite AMD's optimization guide suggesting it.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128452/discussion-between-simon-f-and-peter-cordes).