# Prevent call to v/ucomisd before sqrt

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I am optimizing my code, and coming to this

```
#include <math.h>

typedef double vector __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

double norm_vector(vector u) {
  vector w = u*u;
  return sqrt(w[0]+w[1]);
}
```

I discovered that compiling with

```
gcc -xc -std=gnu11 -O3  -Wall -Wextra -fno-verbose-asm -march=haswell
```

prior the call to `sqrt` a `vucomisd` instruction is executed

```
norm_vector:
        vmulpd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vhaddpd xmm1, xmm0, xmm0
        vsqrtsd xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vucomisd        xmm0, xmm0
        jp      .L13
        ret
.L13:
        sub     rsp, 8
        vmovapd xmm0, xmm1
        call    sqrt
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

is it taking care for the argument of `sqrt` to be non-negative? In the case I want to avoid this call (since by definition the argument will be positive), how to do this?

Comment: Pass `-fno-math-errno` to `gcc`.

Comment: Ah ok, I must be tired... right now... simple. But to do on that function only?

Comment: There's no good reason *not* to pass `-fno-math-errno` to gcc globally. If you want to know whether your floating-point ops encountered an error, you should use the floating-point environment functions *anyway*.

Comment: Yeah, math functions setting `errno` is generally considered to have been a poor design decision and kept around only for backward compatibility, nowadays.

Comment: @zwol: Really glad to hear that it's widely recognized as bad.  I always thought it was the dumbest thing ever that the only reason a lot of math functions don't inline is that they might have to set `errno`.  (And since that requires actually checking for NaNs in lots of cases when the program doesn't care).  Maybe we can hope that gcc will default to `-fno-math-errno` at some point in the future...

Comment: Anyway, @Fabio, gcc has some kind of syntax to `push` and `pop` compiler options with the `__attribute__(())` syntax, IIRC.  You could use that to enable `-ffast-math` on a per-function basis, as well as things like `-mavx` after CPU detection.

Comment: Actually I think I'm mixing that up with MSVC's push/pop option pragmas.  Gcc lets you apply attributes to functions that set compiler options, with no need to undo it to avoid affecting later functions.   e.g. `__attribute__((target ("sse4.2")))` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661659/gcc-6-1-0-using-wrong-instructions-in-sse-intrinsics/40662651#40662651

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I was thinking to __attribute__(()) to set this per function. I think I'll keep `-fno-math-errno` right now it is the easier way to achieve my goal. But thanks a lot.